# How to compute the center of a polygon in 2D and 3D space

Tags: c++, python, matlab, geometry, polygon

Consider a **simple convex polygon** in 2D Cartesian space. If given a list of vertex coordinates sorted in a **counter-clockwise orientation** like this `[[x0, y0], ..., [xn, yn]]`. How could you compute the center of the polygon (the point inside the polygon that is **equidistant to all vertices**)?

Also consider a second case where the polygon is placed in 3D Cartesian space and its normal vector is not parallel to any of the Cartesian axes. How could you compute the center, **without rotating** the polygon?

I can read C/C++, Fortran, MATLAB and Python, however any pseudo-code is also well appreciated.

**EDIT**

I now realise that my question was not well-posed. I am sorry for that. It appears that what I was looking for is the centroid of the polygon (i.e. the point on which a cardboard cut-out would balance while assuming uniform density and a uniform gravity field).

Comment: `mean(x) mean (y)` ? I'm not sure if a point equidistant to all vertices exists for all polygons (e.g. quadrilateral points at (0,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (3,0) ).

Comment: That is not a quadrilateral but a T shape

Comment: In general, most polygons will not have a point that is equidistant to all verticies.  Do you know that they are regular?

Comment: OK the convex hull of those points (move the (0,0) to (-0.0001, 0) if you like). Either way, the centre as you've described doesn't exist in general I think. You could look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon if 'centroid' is what you're after.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You definition of center doesn't make sense in general.

To see this just draw three non-aligned points on a plane and compute the one an only circle that passes for all three points. Clearly your center of the triangle must be the center of this circle.

Now draw a fourth point that doesn't lie on the circle and form the four sided polygon. What is the center? There is no point in the plane that is equidistant from all vertices.

Note also that even in case of triangles using the point equidistant from the vertices can give you points outside and far away from the polygon and is also numerically unstable (given any ε>0 and M>0 you can always build a triangle in which a specific movement of a vertex by a distance of less than ε moves the center by a distance greater than M).

Commonly used "centers" that are simple to compute are the average of all vertices, the average of the boundary, the center of mass or even just the center of the axis-aligned bounding box. All of them can however fall outside the polygon if the polygon is not convex, but in your case they may work.

The simplest reasonable one (because it doesn't depends on the coordinate system) is the barycenter of the vertices (code in Python):

```
xc = sum(x for (x, y) in points) / len(points)
yc = sum(y for (x, y) in points) / len(points)
```

something bad about it it's that just splitting one side of the polygon gives you a different center (in other words it depends on the vertices and not on the set of points bounded by the polygon). The simplest that depends on the polygon is IMO the barycenter of the boundary:

```
sx = sy = sL = 0
for i in range(len(points)):   # counts from 0 to len(points)-1
    x0, y0 = points[i - 1]     # in Python points[-1] is last element of points
    x1, y1 = points[i]
    L = ((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2) ** 0.5
    sx += (x0 + x1)/2 * L
    sy += (y0 + y1)/2 * L
    sL += L
xc = sx / sL
yc = sy / sL
```

For both of them the extension to 3d is trivial... just add `z` using the same formulas.

In the case of a general (not necessarily convex, not necessarily simply connected) polygon a "center" that I found useful but that is not trivial to compute is the (an) inner point that is at a maximum distance from the boundary (in other words a "most inner" point).

In this case I resorted to use a discrete (bitmap) representation and a gaussian distance transform.

Answer (score 4):

First of all for a polygon, the centroid may not always imply equidistant lengths from the centroid to the vertices. In most cases this is probably NOT true. That being said, you can find the centroid simply by finding the mean of your `x` coordinates and the mean of your `y` coordinates. In Matlab: `centroidx = mean(xcoords)` and `centroidy = mean(ycoords)` are the coordinates of the centroid. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) if you really need more.